# C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have written a simple function in C that raises a given number to a given power. The function returns the correct value when I call it in C, but when I call it in Python it returns a different, incorrect value.

I created the shared file using the command:
`$ gcc -fPIC -shared -o test.so test.c`

I have tried different configurations of the C function, some of which return the expected value and some of which do not. For example, when my function a simple square using `return x*x`, without a `for` loop, it returned the correct value in Python.

I hope to eventually be able to call a C function in python that will return a two-dimensional C array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float power(float x, int exponent)
{
    float val = x;
    for(int i=1; i<exponent; i++){
        val = val*x;
    }
    return val;
}
```

```py
from ctypes import *

so_file = '/Users/.../test.so'
functions = CDLL(so_file)

functions.power.argtype = [c_float, c_int]
functions.power.restype = c_float

print(functions.power(5,3))
```

I obtain the expected output of 125.0 when I call the function in C, but when I call the function in python, it returns a value of 0.0.

This is my first time using ctypes. Have I made an obvious error that is causing the function to miscalculate?

Comment: `argtypes` (ending with `s`). [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

In order for everything to be properly converted (*Python* <=> *C*) when calling the function (residing in a *.dll* (*.so*)), 2 things need to be specified (leaving *x86* (*pc032*) calling convention (*Win*) aside):

1. Argument types
2. Return type

In *CTypes*, this is achieved by specifying:

1. ***argtypes*** - a sequence (tuple, list) containing each function's argument (*CTypes*) type, in the order they appear in the function declaration (if the function only has one argument, there should be **one element sequence**)
2. ***restype*** - a single *CTypes* type (function's return type)

Side note: an alternative to the above, is prototyping foreign functions (***CFUNCTYPE***, ***WINFUNCTYPE***, ***PYFUNCTYPE*** - check the ***Function prototypes*** section (in the *URL* at the beginning)).

Anyway:

- **Failing to specify**
- **Misspelling** (which basically is same thing as previous bullet)

**any of them** (where required <sup>(1)</sup>), will result in defaults being applied: **all are treated (*C89* style) as *int*s, which** (on most systems) **are 32 bits long.

This generates *Undefined Behavior* <sup>(2)</sup>** (also applies when **incorrectly specifying** them), especially on *064bit* *CPU* / *OS* (and *Python* process), where **values of larger types** (e.g. pointers) **could be truncated** (check [[SO]: Maximum and minimum value of C types integers from Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485502/4788546) for details (limits -> size) regarding *C* integral types).
The displayed errors can be numerous and sometimes misleading.

You misspelled ***argtype*** (lacking an ***s*** at the end).

Correct that, and you should be fine

**Example**:

For a function *func* exported by *libdll.dll* (*libdll.so*) with the following header:

```c
double func(uint32_t ui32,
            float f,
            long long vll[8],
            void *pv,
            char *pc,
            uint8_t *pui8);
```

The *Python* equivalent would be:

```py
import ctypes as cts

func = libdll.func
func.argtypes = (cts.c_uint32,
                 cts.c_float,
                 cts.c_longlong * 8,
                 cts.c_void_p,
                 cts.c_char_p,
                 cts.POINTER(cts.c_ubyte))
'''
Last 2 argument types are almost the same (1st is signed while 2nd is unsigned).
  - 1st is used for NUL terminated strings (that work with strcpy, strlen, ...).
    Python automatically converts them to bytes

  - 2nd is used for buffers in general (which may contain NUL (0x00) characters)
'''

func.restype = cts.c_double
```

**Some (more destructive) outcomes** of the same (or very similar) scenario (there are many others):

- **[[SO]: Python ctypes cdll.LoadLibrary, instantiate an object, execute its method, private variable address truncated (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52272969/4788546)**
- **[[SO]: python ctypes issue on different OSes (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53185316/4788546)**

---

#### Footnotes

- ***#1***: Technically, there are situations where it's not required to specify them. But even then, it's best to have them specified in order to eliminate any possible confusion:

  - Function with no arguments:

    ```py
    function_from_dll.argtypes = ()
    ```
  - Function returning *void*:

    ```py
    function_from_dll.restype = None
    ```
- ***#2***: ***U**ndefined **B**ehavior* ([[Wikipedia]: Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)) as the name suggests, is a situation when the outcome of a piece of code can't be "predicted" (or guaranteed by the *C* (*C++*) standard). The main cases:

  - Works as expected
  - Doesn't work as expected

    - Has some funny outputs / side effects
    - Crashes

  The "beauty" of it is that sometimes it seems totally random, sometimes it "only reproduces" under some specific circumstances (different machines, different *OS*es, different environments, ...). Bottom line is that **all of them are purely coincidental! The problem lies in the code** (can be the current code (highest chances) or other code it uses (libraries, compilers)).